# DataGrip - Exception

Tags: datagrip, intellij-datagrip

When I try to connect to a db I am receiving this error message in DataGrip:

```
[2019-07-30 20:16:54] Illegal embedded sign character.
[2019-07-30 20:16:54] com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Illegal embedded sign character
```

My current version is `2019.2` . IF I try to connect to my local db. It works. But for external dbs I'm getting that message.

I invalided the cache and restarted several times.

Any idea ?

Comment: Hi! I am Max from DataGrip. Please send us logs to datagrip@jetbrains.com
They can be found in Help | Compress logs...

Comment: Hi @moscas . I already raised an issue . See request : 2199314. Basically I needed to remove the content of the file : `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and now it works!